# Testing a long running process

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a time consuming operation that needs tested. The operation makes changes to a database. Current, the majority of my tests are very similar, a query is performed on the database to determine the expected result after the operation. Then, the operation under test is ran. Finally, the database is again queried to determine if the expected condition has been met. Since I am only querying the database in each test to determine the expected and actual results, and the function under test is always performing the same operations on the database. Is there a way that I could run the operation once and still test each condition in its own test?

Comment: why don't you use unit tests?

Comment: yeah, like daryal said, just use unit testing. First mock your database so it returns a certain result - let's say it returns "A". Then your code under test should change your result to "B" and you can assert to see if your code called the database with "B".

Answer (score 2):

The standard strategy for running unit tests on code that has side effects such as connecting to databases is to provide mock objects instead of a real database connection or other service, but it depending on how your code is structured this may be harder or easier to adopt.

Frameworks for inversion of control and dependency injection can be very helpful for this kind of purpose. The dependancy injection pattern makes sure that objects can have dependant implementations passed to them at runtime, rather than constructing them directly, for testing purposes or just to create more modular code. [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) is such a framework for C#, but there are others, such as Spring.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to be using Unit Testing Frameworks and/or Mocking Frameworks.

As a general rule, you shouldn't be writing additional queries to test the query has worked as expected on the database as these themselves will require development and testing.

Depending on the database you're writing to, you may be able to get the number of rows affected on the database (take a look at @@rowcount for SQL Server). But again, you're adding additional code just to do testing which should really be a separate activity.